# Alternative to Spyder?

Tags: python, ipython, sublimetext3, spyder

I am looking for something that will work like Spyder, and at the same time, would be fast as Sublime Text. The problem with Sublime Text is that it lacks the IPython Console like the one Spyder has, and Syder lacks the speed (both the start up speed and code execution speed) that Sublime Text has. Is there anything in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to code an extense program structured I will use the [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE.

If you want to create some notebooks, with experiments and results I will use [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: I am looking for an ide with IPython built into it.